# execution order influenced space complexity in haskell

Tags: haskell

i am reading about haskell in wikibook:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Graph_reduction

and in the article, there is an example that puzzles me:

> Tricky space leak example:
>
> ```
> (\xs -> head xs + last xs) [1..n]
> (\xs -> last xs + head xs) [1..n]
> ```
>
> The first version runs on O(1) space. The second in O(n).

how come?

I assume `last` is implemented like following:

```
last [] = error ""
last [r] = r
last (_:t) = last t
```

so a tail recursion should take constant space. why the second one would yield linear space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer has to be that when evaluating `a + b`, the expression `a` gets evaluated before `b` in practice.

Normally `last xs` only takes O(1) space - the elements of `xs` can be discarded as `last` traverses down the list. However, if `xs` is needed for another expression, the expansion of `xs` must be kept in memory for the other expression, and this is what is happening in the second case since it appears that `xs` is needed for `head`.

In the first case `head xs` is evaluated "first" which only evaluates the first element of `xs`. Then `last xs` is evaluated, traversing down the list. But since there isn't any further need for the elements of the list they may be discarded during the traversal.

Comment: Is this guaranteed anywhere, as part of some spec? Or is it just a quirk of how `+` works in GHC that it happens to evaluate its first argument first, and a different Haskell implementation could choose to evaluate the second argument of `+` first while still conforming to the spec?

Comment: The Haskell language spec does not specify the order of evaluation. It doesn't even specify that results must be cached - i.e. in `f a + g a` an implementation could decide to evaluate `a` twice. Since every expression in Haskell is pure you would get the same result.